# Error while trying to get backup c# localdb

Tags: c#, localdb

I'm trying to get the backup of a database but I am getting the error
"database does not exist".

```
string master_ConnectionString = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;Database=Master;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
string database = GetDataDirectory();

MessageBox.Show(database);

using (SqlConnection masterdbConn = new SqlConnection())
{
    masterdbConn.ConnectionString = master_ConnectionString;
    masterdbConn.Open();

    using (SqlCommand multiuser_rollback_dbcomm = new SqlCommand())
    {
         multiuser_rollback_dbcomm.Connection = masterdbConn;
         multiuser_rollback_dbcomm.CommandText = @"ALTER DATABASE @DBNAME SET MULTI_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE";
         multiuser_rollback_dbcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBNAME",database);
         multiuser_rollback_dbcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    masterdbConn.Close();
}

        //SqlConnection.ClearAllPools();

        //using (SqlConnection backupConn = new SqlConnection())
        //{
        //    backupConn.ConnectionString = "Data Source=(LocalDB)\\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\\BbCon.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;";
        //    backupConn.Open();

        //    using (SqlCommand backupcomm = new SqlCommand())
        //    {
        //        backupcomm.Connection = backupConn;
        //        backupcomm.CommandText = @"BACKUP DATABASE BbCon TO DISK='c:\yourdbname.bak'";
        //        backupcomm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DBNAME", database);
        //        backupcomm.ExecuteNonQuery();
        //    }
        //    backupConn.Close();
        //}
```

Database name is BbCon.mdf it is located at C:\Users\asus\Desktop\New Folder (3)\bbcon_accout_software\bbcon_accout_software\bin\x86\Debug

[image]

Comment: Can you try changing the casing to `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB`...just a shot

Comment: i tried but no change same error

Comment: As I said, (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB is for SQL localDB 2014 . Use your previous one for 2012.

Answer (score 2):

Please try below code

```
public string constring = @"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\MyDataBase.mdf;Integrated Security=True";

try
{ 
 SaveFileDialog sd = new SaveFileDialog();
 sd.Filter = "SQL Server database backup files|*.bak";
 sd.Title = "Create Database Backup";
 sd.FileName = "MyDataBase-" + string.Format("{0:dd-MM-yyyy_hh-mm-ss-tt}", DateTime.Now);

 if (sd.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
 {
  using (bcon = new SqlConnection(constring))
  {
   string sqlStmt = string.Format("backup database [" + System.Windows.Forms.Application.StartupPath + "\\MyDataBase.mdf] to disk='{0}'", sd.FileName);
   using (SqlCommand bu2 = new SqlCommand(sqlStmt, bcon))
   {
    bcon.Open();
    bu2.ExecuteNonQuery();
    bcon.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("Backup Created Sucessfully");
   }
  }
 }
}
catch (Exception){MessageBox.Show("Backup Not Created");}
```

Try to change your connection string as i have suggested, still it will not work then you can use above code. It was work for me like charm.

Comment: thanks for your code when i tried above code i get same error in question